# ssas hierarchy member and hierarchy level members difference

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cube, ssas-2008, ssas-2008-r2

The ssas dimension, Period consists of an hierarchy, [period calendar] and there are 2 levels [period year] and [period name].

There are members under **[period name]** (level members) and also, there are members under **[members]** folder. What are the differences between these two set of members? These two sets look the same.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are two ways of accessing the same members.   Drag them onto an MDX query to see how they would be expressed in MDX.